# closure example using setTimeout not recognizing function call

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, closures, settimeout

I am trying to create a small application that closes over the `delay` function and defines a new function using a callback and a wait time. I then wanted to use this newly created inner `setTimeout` function to take a single parameter that would be run on the callback after the wait time.

```js
function addTwo(num) {
  return num + 2
}

const delay = (callback, wait) => {
  return setTimeout((value) => callback(value), wait)
}
var delayAddByTwo = delay(addTwo, 100)
console.log(delayAddByTwo(6))
// expected result 8 
// actual result --- Uncaught TypeError: delayAddByTwo is not a function
```

As far as I can tell after the `delayAddByTwo = delay(addTwo, 100)` the only parameter left to create is the `value` passed to callback inside the 'inner' `setTimeOut` function. What am I missing about closure in this example?

Comment: `setTimeout` will return its id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make delay return another function which accepts `n`. This `n` represents the number which will be passed into `addTwo` (ie the callback). `setTimeout` by default will return its [`timeoutID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value), so, instead, you can return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), which resolves to the result of calling `addTwo` with `n`. In order to get your result from the Promise, you can [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) it within an [`async` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

See example below:

```js
const addTwo = num => num + 2;
const delay = (callback, wait) => n => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, wait, callback(n)));

(async () => {
  const delayAddByTwo = delay(addTwo, 1000);
  const res = await delayAddByTwo(6);
  console.log(res);
})();
```

Above I have used the [third argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Arguments) of `setTimeout`, which will be used as the first argument of the callback and passed to `res`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `var delayAddByTwo = delay(addTwo, 100)` by `var delayAddByTwo = (num) => {  delay(() => {addTwo(num)}, 100);}`

```js
function addTwo(num) {
  console.log(num + 2)
  return num + 2
}

const delay = (callback, wait) => {
  setTimeout(callback, wait)
}
var delayAddByTwo = (num) => {
  delay(() => {addTwo(num)}, 100);
}
console.log(delayAddByTwo)
delayAddByTwo(6)
// expected result 8 
// actual result --- Uncaught TypeError: delayAddByTwo is not a function
```

Comment: You can use `setTimeout(callback, wait)` instead of `setTimeout((value) => callback(value), wait)` - `value` isn't being used

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
var delayAddByTwo = delay(addTwo, 100)
```

To

```
const delayAddByTwo = delay => (addTwo, 100)
```